# Libreoffice Writer font display glitches

Tags: macos, fonts, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

On my Mac I have a problem with the display of fonts onscreen in LibreOffice Writer. (NB: User @fixer1234 replicated the problem on Linux.) Somehow letter combinations don't line out well within a word. They're too close or too wide apart. See the screenshot. These are all single words. I've taken screenshots, and put them together in one picture.

Fonts used: Times New Roman (screenshot) and Liberation Serif. I see this with other fonts as well. On the screenshot you see two columns with the same words. The words on the left are worse than on the right. The words on the right are definitely better, but still not what I expect. If I export to PDF, it is how it should be.

The words on the right side are all first words on a line, with no other text. It looks like making it a sentence creates this problem, like when you justify text, but this text is not justified. All is left-aligned.

- maken: `ak` seems to close, `ke` too wide, `en` too close
- geboekt: `eb` too close, `boe` too wide, `ekt` seems right
- gehad: `eh` too close
- probleemloos: `obl` too wide, `lo` too close
- heb: `he` too wide, `eb` too close
- handen: `ha` too wide, `an` too close, `nde` too wide

[image: Font glitches]

**What causes this and how can I get the fonts to display properly?**

Comment: Does changing fonts size make it better?

Comment: It does change, but then the problem just moves on to other letter combinations. See my edited question plus the new screenshot.

Comment: I use LO in Linux and was able to replicate your problem.  I loaded the Liberation fonts.  I didn't get exactly the same problem spacing, but other letter combinations had the same type of issue.  It's font-specific.  LO doesn't do a good job with certain fonts.  When I applied other fonts, the spacing was appropriate.  Try, for example, one of the DejaVu fonts, which are often used as default system fonts.

Comment: It may have to do with how the application uses (or doesn't use) the layout hinting embedded with the font.

Comment: @fixer1234 - that doesn't explain the difference in the screenshot.

Comment: I don't know for sure why LO has a problem with some fonts.  Somebody would need to know the algorithms that the LO developers use for rendering fonts.   I can only tell you that it produced the same type of problem for me with the same font on a different platform, but produced proper spacing with other fonts.  All I can suggest is to use a font that it handles well.  My best explanation is "yes, it does that because it sucks with certain kinds of fonts".  :-)  BTW, this is an excellent question.  +1